# play if the player click in a blank space unity 2d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I'm making a 2d game for mobile and created a pause button on the canvas. the problem is that when i click the pause button the player shoots. I wish there was a way to block the shot when the touch is on an element of the UI.
is there any simple way to do this?

this is the code I wrote to detect clicks:

```
if(Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            touch_ = Input.GetTouch(0);
            
            if(touch_.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            {
                touching = true;
                touch_began_fun();
            }
            if(tocando)
            {
                toching_fun();
            }
            if(touch_.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
            {
                touching = false;
                touch_ended_fun();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the current selected game object of the EventSystem is null. If it is not null, the touch is on a UI element.

```
if(Input.touchCount > 0)
{
    touch_ = Input.GetTouch(0);

    if(touch_.phase == TouchPhase.Began && EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject == null)
    {
        touching = true;
        touch_began_fun();
    }
    if(tocando)
    {
        toching_fun();
    }
    if(touch_.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
    {
        touching = false;
        touch_ended_fun();
    }
}
```